# Do any $\ell^{p}(\omega)$ have the extension property?

Tags: banach-spaces, noncommutative-algebra

**Definition 1.**
*A metric space (normed space) $X$ has the **extension property** exactly in case, for all finite $A\subseteq X$ and isometric (linear isometric) $f:A\rightarrow X$, there exists an extension to a global isometry (global linear isometry) $\hat{f}:X\rightarrow X$ with $\hat{f}\hspace{-0.25em}\upharpoonright\hspace{-0.25em} A=f$.*

One can define the notion for other structures too. The main point is, maps are restricted to structure preserving partial isomorphisms, and to extend these to global isomorphisms.

**Question 1.** Does any Banach space $\ell^{p}(\omega)$ for some $p\in[1,\infty]$ exhibit the extension property? If so, for which $p$? (Here $\omega=\mathbb{N}$.)

In particular, I mainly wish to know about the cases $p\in\{1,\infty\}$.

---

**Remark 1.** An additional requirement on $f$ is that the linear extension of $f$ be well-defined and linear, that is, for all $n\in\omega$ it holds:

$$\sum_{i<n}c_{i}f(a_{i})=0\Longleftrightarrow\sum_{i<n}c_{i}a_{i}=0$$

for all vectors $(a_{i})_{i<n}\subseteq A$ and scalars $(c_{i})_{i<n}$. (The $\Longleftarrow$-direction relates to well-definedness, and the $\Longrightarrow$-direction refers to injectivity.)

Comment: Do you require $\hat f$ to be onto? "Isometry" could be understood either way.

Comment: In my case, I am not looking for a surjective extension $\hat{f}\supset f$. (One can at any rate later work this in with the sought result via a back-and-forth argument.)

Comment: How do you define *linear isometric* maps on finite sets?

Comment: Sorry, I have not posed the problem here as I am actually looking at it (in my concrete case). The starting set $A$ is to be finitely _generated_.

Answer (score 1):

Being able to extend an isometry to an isometry is rare. I don't think any nontrivial Banach space has this property. Here is a proof for $\ell^1$ and $\ell^\infty$,  the two spaces of main interest to you. In both cases $e_1,e_2,\dots$ is the standard set of $0-1$ vectors, e.g. $e_2=(0,1,0,0,\dots)$.

#### The case of $\ell^1$

Let $A=\{0,e_1,e_2\}$. Define $f(0)=0$, $f(e_1)=e_1$, $f(e_2)=-e_1$. This is an isometry. Suppose it extends to an isometry of $\ell^1$. Let $y = f((e_1+e_2)/2)$. Since $(e_1+e_2)/2$ is at distance $1$ from every element of $1$, it follows that 
$$\|y\|=1, \quad \|y-e_1\|=1, \quad \|y+e_1\|=1$$
This is a contradiction, since the only element for which $\|y-e_1\|=1$ and $\|y+e_1\|=1$ is $y=0$.

#### The case of $\ell^\infty$

Let $A=\{e_1+e_2,e_1-e_2,-e_1-e_2,-e_1+e_2\}$, i.e., the vertices of the square $(\pm 1,\pm1)$. Let $f$ fix the points $e_1+e_2$ and $e_1-e_2$, and exchange the points $-e_1-e_2$ and $-e_1+e_2$. This is an isometry. Suppose it has an extension to $\ell_\infty$. Let $y=f(e_1/2+e_2)$ and $z = f(e_1/2-e_2)$. Then 
$$  \|y-(e_1+e_2)\|=\|(e_1/2+e_2)-(e_1+e_2)\|= \frac12 \tag{1}$$
$$ \|y-(-e_1-e_2)\|= \|(e_1/2+e_2)-(-e_1+e_2)\| = \frac32 \tag{2} $$
from where it follows that $y = \frac12e_1+\frac12 e_2+\sum_{k\ge 3} c_k e_k$ with $|c_k|\le \frac12$. 
Similarly, 
$$  \|z-(e_1-e_2)\|=\|(e_1/2-e_2)-(e_1-e_2)\|= \frac12 \tag{3}$$
$$ \|z-(-e_1+e_2)\|= \|(e_1/2-e_2)-(-e_1-e_2)\| = \frac32 \tag{4} $$
from where it follows that $z = \frac12e_1-\frac12 e_2+\sum_{k\ge 3} d_k e_k$ with $|d_k|\le \frac12$.

Thus, $\|y-z\|=1$. But this is a contradiction because
$$\|(e_1/2+e_2) - (e_1/2-e_2)\|=2$$

Comment: Thanks for the counter-examples. A few questions: in the case $\ell^{1}$, is it intentional, that $f(e_{1})=e_{1}$ and $f(e_{2})=-e_{1}$ or did you mean to write $f(e_{2})=-e_{2})$? I assume it was intended: in this case, the failure is more in-built, because no linear extension of $f$ is injectiv. What if I further demand that the linear extension $f$ be injective?

Comment: (Same remark to the $\ell^{\infty}$ case --- the failure to be an isometry has more to do with the failure in being able to be extended to a linear function.)